# How could I store information about users without registration?

Tags: php, email, registration, confirmation

I am just developing a PHP website and I would like to store some information about user's behavior (like: How many times did a user vote on an article? or How many times did the users start an article?) without the need of the user to register.

I don't want to violate the laws. I don't want to violate the data storage laws and all of these stuff, but I would like to find an easier way than registering to store some information about my site's usage.

I thought of confirmation with an email address and a specific question (like: What is the name of my city where I live?).

What do you think? What should I do?

Comment: "I thought of confirmation with an email address and a specific question..." How is that not registration?

Comment: I would store the email address in a SESSION not by all means in a db.

Comment: Sessions expire. It does not sound like you fully understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

What about just using [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid)? [Many major sites are OpenID providers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid#OpenID_Providers), so it's very likely that any given user of your site will already have an identity which they could use.

http://openid.net/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already thought of OpenID and I think, I could make a more dynamic alternative.

Comment: _"I could make a more dynamic alternative."_ What does that mean? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: No, but an own piece of code could be more suitable and more customizable for me...

Comment: I didn't ask a yes/no question, and on top of that, you haven't actually explained why OpenID is not suitable/customizable for you. But hey, you asked for our opinions. It sounds like you have your heart set on a custom implementation, and if that's the case, I'm not going to waste my time trying to convince you to do otherwise.

Comment: I have got a very complicated piece of code. It would take (I think) more time to make it fit in than write a similar code And it would look more professional and more "brandable".

Answer (score 0):

I would use cookies to track them.  I would also check out [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), you may find it can track everything you are interested and it gives you nice graphs and reports that are easy to read.

Comment: Without making them login or identify themselves some other way that will always be a problem.  Maybe it's acceptable, maybe it's not; it depends on how accurate you need the tracking to be.  The only way to be completely accurate is to make them login.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you whats legal and what isn't but I work for a company that records statistics about online advertisements.

One of the statistics we collect is unique users we do this based on a combination of identifiers.

These being IP Address, Browser User Agent and a HTTP cookie all combined into a string and hashed to get a unique identifier.

Now this may fall apart for users with dynamic IPs, so a cookie may be suitable enough or any combination of the things above

Comment: IP addresses change. Users log in from different devices, different browsers on the same computer, different physical locations. Browser user agents change when browser versions change. Different users might share computers. Sounds like a pretty unreliable way to identify users to me. Oh, and a person is not synonymous with a computer.